DAX Measure to return column values based on slicer
I am a little bit new to Power BI and wanted to know if this is possible please.
Lets say I have multiple tables with same schema but different values
So imagine I have below tables with just one column
Table 1
Col1
A
B
C
and then Table 2
Col1
D
E
F
I have another table that holds my column names to select
ColumnList
Col1
Col2
I create a slicer with a dropdown list of ColumnList
and finally I have a table on my screen
If a user selects Col1 then i Want to display the values
A
B
C
and user selects Col2 then i want to display values
D
E
F
I tried to create a new measure but it looks like i need to provide aggregated value like max, min, etc etc which will get me one value but i want all rows to be returned

MeasureColumn = IF(SELECTEDVALUE(TaggleTable[col]) = "Col1", max(Table1[Col1]))


can you let me know how to achieve this please?

H,ello, I think you would need to use a working table containing all of your columns values and their origin (A, col1; B, col1; ... F, col2

You can use the inbuilt field parameter feature to achieve this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/power-bi-field-parameters

Thank you. This looks like a nice feature but unfortunately i dont have this on my installation yet (restricted by IT on when I can get the product upgrades)

Field parameters were introduced a long time ago. Tell your IT team that Power BI is updated monthly and the Power BI service has a big dependency on having the latest version of Power BI Desktop installed.
